# Help me parsing the following file format

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, string

I need to parse third party text file in the following format

```
WE BUY  : 10 000.00 USD                      
VALUE   : 281210
RATE    : 30.2600
```

So the general pattern is

**TAG,some separator,:,someseparator,VALUE**

Let;s say i started with `File.ReadAllLines` so I am dealing with individual lines.

What is the best way to parse values?

**UPDATE**

I don't have any documentation for the format but let's say that it is position-based.

1) ":" is always 9th charcter in the string,
2) VALUE is 11th character.
3) Unused spaces are filled with space character.

Let's talk about that format.

**UPDATE 2**

I am thinking about if RegEx is better here? For instance let's say I have a subtask
find

`RATE    : 30.2600`

in the whole text and extract 30.2600 given that is starts with 11th character

Comment: leppie, what about the separators (spaces) between "TAG" , ":" and "VALUE"

Comment: I think you start with File.__Read__AllLines

Comment: Your pattern does not match the entries in the textfile? the commas and is 'some separator' always the same?

Comment: PoweRoy, I am thinking that ":" is always 9th position and VALUE starts always 11th position. The rest is filled with spaces. I don't have any documentation but it looks very much like that.

Comment: If you are sure about the 11th position then try this regular expression: string pattern = "^(?<TAG>.{10})(?<VALUE>.+)$";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Each line:

```
   string[]  parts = line.Split(':');
   // assert parts.Length == 2
   string tag = parts[0].Trim();
   string[] values = parts[1].Split(' ', SplitOptions.NoDupes);  // or ','
```

Comment: You can remove the assertion if you do `line.Split(':', 2)` instead. Assuming the keys do not contain colons, themselves, though.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the parsing of the data read from file, consider using Regular Expressions. In this case you have to be alert though for the delimiter i.e. make sure the delimiter (: in our case) is not accidentally found in the tag or value parts.

---

```
            string pattern = "^(?<TAG>[^:]+):(?<VALUE>.+)$";

        string dataReadFromFile = "WE BUY  : 10 000.00 USD\r\nVALUE   : 281210 \r\nRATE    : 30.2600\r\n";

        Regex rx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline); // Multiline important

        MatchCollection mc = rx.Matches(dataReadFromFile);

        foreach (Match m in mc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}->{1}", m.Groups["TAG"].Value.Trim(), m.Groups["VALUE"].Value.Trim());
        }
```

---

Try this and see if it works for you. If not tell me more info to update it. Hope it will be usefull.