# Need advice parsing decimal value from the string

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, string

I need to parse quantity as decimal and currency code as string.

Input string

```
302 600.00 RUB
10 000.00 USD
```

The pattern is

1. QUANTITY->SPACE->CURRENCYCODE
2. TWO DECIMAL DIGITS
3. Space as thousand separator, dot as decimal separator

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help me parsing the following file format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712052/help-me-parsing-the-following-file-format)

Comment: You'll probably need a regular expression for this

Comment: Henk, in that question I was asking how to parse value and tag. Here I am asking different matter, how to parse specific value. I am thinking it would be better to split that in two question, if you think it is better to have it as one question I will delete that question and update the first one.

Comment: They look to me like 2 steps in an already very localized problem. So yes, close one and try to be specific about the format. Too much guessing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Regex** with accumulators, custom **NumberFormat**

```
string pattern = @"(?<decimal>[0-9]{0,3}(\s[0-9]{3})*(.[0-9]+){0,1})\s" +
                 @"(?<currency>[a-zA-Z]+){1}";

string input = "302 600.00 RUB\r\n10 000.00 USD"; 

// Get text that matches regular expression pattern.
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

NumberFormatInfo format = new NumberFormatInfo();
format.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";
format.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
format.NumberDecimalDigits = 2;

Dictionary<string, decimal> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    dictionary.Add(match.Groups["currency"].Value, Decimal.Parse(match.Groups["decimal"].Value, format));      
}
if (dictionary.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, decimal> item in dictionary)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Currency : {0} Amount: {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
Currency : RUB Amount: 302600,00
Currency : USD Amount: 10000,00
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't tested but you could do something like this.

```
string text = "302 600.00 RUB";
decimal amount;
string type;

var lastspace = text.lastIndexOf(" ");    
decimal.TryParse(text.substring(0, lastspace - 1), out amount);
type = text.substring(lastspace + 1);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh great. String.LastIndex, that's what I need.

Comment: Now, question number two: "302 600.00 RUB            ". Here text.lastIndexOf does not work.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

[...]

```
string sInput = "302 10 600.00 RUB";
// string sInput = "302 600.00 RUB";
// string sInput = "10 000.00 USD";

var rgmResult = Regex.Match(sInput, @"^(?<qty>\d+) (?<price>\d{1,3}( \d{3})*\.\d{2}) (?<cur>[A-Z]{3})$");
string sQuantity = rgmResult.Groups["qty"].Value;
string sPrice = rgmResult.Groups["price"].Value;
string sCurrency = rgmResult.Groups["cur"].Value;
```

Comment: Ouch @"^(?<quantity>[0-9]+) (?<price>[0-9]{1,3}( [0-9]{3})*\.[0-9]{2}) (?<currency>[A-Z]{3})$" looks nasty!  Might be the only way though

Comment: That's the price to pay (no pun intended!) to get it right :)